# RxAndroid Simplify a common pattern?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I find myself writing over and over again:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe</* some type */>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super /* some type */> subscriber) {
            try {
                subscriber.onNext(/* do something */);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
```

for network operations.

Is there any way to make it less repetative ?

Answer (score 2):

The first `create` can be replaced by `fromCallable`.

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> calculationReturnsAValue());
```

The application of schedulers can be achieved by creating a Transformer:

```
Transformer schedulers = o -> 
    o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

and composing with it:

```
source.compose(schedulers);
```

Comment: is the exception handling being done with `fromCallable()` ?